# How to retrieve image name from db and set into PHPEXCEL?

Tags: phpexcel

I am getting image name from database and set the image into PHPExcel but i am facing the error
  Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing::setImageResource()

Comment: How are you trying to set the image into PHPExcel? Show code, don't make us guess.

Comment: But setImageResource() is only a valid method for memory drawings (the `PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing` object), see `/Examples/25inmemoryimage.php` for an example of how to use this

Comment: If your image is from a disk file, then just use normal Worksheet drawings (the `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` object) as shown in `/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php`

Comment: Hi Mark Baker,
   $objDrawing->setName('image title');    
   $objDrawing->setImageResource($Image);
   $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PNG);
   $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
   $objDrawing->setHeight(36);             
   $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');   
   $objDrawing->setOffsetX(10);             
   $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

Comment: Edit all relevant code into your answer, starting with how you instantiate $objDrawing

Comment: And are you trying to insert an image that is a file on you disk, or a blob in your database?

Comment: $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();   I created the object for PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing and already i stored the image into my localhost db. Example logo.png. Now using above code i retrieve image from database. I stored image in db only it;s not in my disk that image is not in my disk.

Comment: Well if you're instantiating a `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing`, then you shouldn't be using methods for `PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing`.... they are two very different things. Take a look at the images being inserted in `/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php`

Comment: Hi Mark Baker,                                                                                             Just file name logo.png only i inserted into into db. Using above my code how can i retrieve image from db.                                                                        Thanks

Comment: Then your file is on disk, use the relevant code from `/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php` as the basis for your code, and replace the reference `$objDrawing->setPath('./images/officelogo.jpg');` to reference your own image file instead

Answer (score 0):

If your file is on disk, then use the relevant code from `/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php` as the basis for your code, and replace the reference `$objDrawing->setPath('./images/phpexcel_logo.gif');` to reference your own image file instead

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('PHPExcel logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('PHPExcel logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/phpexcel_logo.gif'); // reference your image file here
$objDrawing->setHeight(36);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('D24');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(10);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Comment: I retrieve file alone from database eg. $img = logo.png and i set the image file into $objDrawing->setPath($img); but it shows the logo.ong file not found. My image for mat may be png, gif, jpg or peg. How can i fix this problem. my images are not stored in local disk, it stored in database only.

Comment: If you're getting the actual image bytestream as data from a database, then you need to set `$objDrawing` as a Memory Drawing, not as a Worksheet Drawing: `$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();`

Comment: $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing(); $objDrawing->setName('logo'); $objDrawing->setImageResource($img); $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_DE‌​FAULT); $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT); $objDrawing->setHeight(100); $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1'); $objDrawing->setOffsetX(10); $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()); I gave the the code like above. It's not show any error but it doesnot get the image it shows empty

Comment: In database the image field name is 'name' and varchar(255) data type

Comment: If you're storing an actual image in the database, then you should be using a blob rather than varchar.... if you're storing the image filename... then you should be using the code that I provided in my original answer and just using that filename in the path.... but as a full filesystem reference and not a url or relative to the web root directory